# Why Google Play don't know that I want only small and Normal screen?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, manifest, android-screen-support

I've created two apps. One for tablets and one for smartphone.

For tablets, it works great. I've changed the `manifest` and put `"true" to large and xlarge screen.` 
So when I uploaded my apk, Google says 982 devices (so it excludes phones)

BUT, for smartphones, I've put `"false" for large and xlarge` and Google Play doesn't see that ! It says 4700 devices compatible and I see in the list that Tablets are compatible !

Do you know why ?

Here's my manifest for smartphone :

```
<android>
    <manifestAdditions><![CDATA[<manifest>
        <supports-screens
            android:smallScreens="true"
            android:normalScreens="true"
            android:largeScreens="false"
            android:xlargeScreens="false"/>
          <compatible-screens>
            <!-- list the screens you support here -->
            <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
            <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
            <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
            <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
            <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
            <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
            <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
            <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
          </compatible-screens>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    </manifest>]]></manifestAdditions>
        </android>
          <supportedLanguages>fr</supportedLanguages>
        </application>
```

Did I make a mistake somewhere ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do you know why ?

Get rid of `<supports-screens>` and only have your `<compatible-screens>` element. Also note that you will not be available on all `small` and `normal` screens, as there are more densities than what you have listed.